# MySQL 5.7 trying to improve performance

Tags: mysql, database-performance

We have a PHP app running against MySQL 5.7 with innoDB.
The app used to be really slow. MySQL takes 100% of the CPU for a really long time, for some queries.
I tried running optimize table, which innoDB just interprets as re-create table. This made matters only worse.

I enabled slow query logging as:

```
slow_query_log          = ON
long_query_time         = 5
log_queries_not_using_indexes = ON
slow_query_log_file     = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
```

I only see the below in the log, repeated many times:

```
SET timestamp=1516955047;
SELECT * FROM `notification` WHERE `user_id`=4 ORDER BY `created_at` DESC LIMIT 5;
# Time: 2018-01-26T08:24:07.652626Z
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id:   153
# Query_time: 0.000221  Lock_time: 0.000107 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 3
SET timestamp=1516955047;
SELECT
    kcu.constraint_name,
    kcu.column_name,
    kcu.referenced_table_name,
    kcu.referenced_column_name
FROM information_schema.referential_constraints AS rc
JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu ON
    (
        kcu.constraint_catalog = rc.constraint_catalog OR
        (kcu.constraint_catalog IS NULL AND rc.constraint_catalog IS NULL)
    ) AND
    kcu.constraint_schema = rc.constraint_schema AND
    kcu.constraint_name = rc.constraint_name
WHERE rc.constraint_schema = database() AND kcu.table_schema = database()
AND rc.table_name = 'notification' AND kcu.table_name = 'notification';
# Time: 2018-01-26T08:24:07.653082Z
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id:   153
# Query_time: 0.000155  Lock_time: 0.000040 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 143
```

I want something to go on, to be able whether performance could be improved with database tuning. How do I see a list of missing indices or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

To analyze MySQL slow log, try tool **mysqldumpslow** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldumpslow.html

```
mysqldumpslow /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
```

When you find slowest query, try **EXPLAIN** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html
It's easy to use:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT foo FROM slow_something WHERE ...;
```